# js2py.internals.simplex.JsException: ReferenceError: Audio is not defined

Tags: javascript, audio, python-3.5

I have one `wav` file I tried to call this file using js so I trying that

```
import js2py

data = '''var snd = new Audio("file.wav"); 
snd.play();
'''

data = js2py.eval_js(data)
print(data)
```

but when trying to execute that time Audio is not defined so how to call js in python with music file?